# How do you find the average of numbers in excel based on criteria in other cells?

Tags: excel

I have a fair bit of data I am trying to make smaller. My data is arranged in minutes following an event with associated sugar readings (see below):

> 469 13.3
>   471 
>   474 13.5
>   479 14.1
>   484 14.3
>   489 14.3
>   494 14
>   499 13.9
>   504 14.2
>   509 13.9
>   514 13.7
>   519 13.4
>   524 13.5
>   529 13.8
>   534 14.1
>   539 14.3
>   544 14.1
>   549 13.8
>   554 13.2
>   559 12.9
>   564 12.9
>   569 12.8
>   574 12.4
>   579 12.1
>   584 11.9
>   589 11.7
>   594 11.7
>   599 11.8
>   604 11.7

The minute readings go up to ~4500. I was wondering if there is a way to find the average of the sugar readings based on time criteria - e.g. find the sugar average for every 20 minute group. I also have time data as well if this helps (e.g. 10/12/2013 13:53)?

Thanks for your help!

Alternatively is there a way to add in numbers between the minute values with blank spaces between the sugar values - that is:

Instead of this:

> 469   13.3
>   471
>   474   13.5
>   479   14.1
>   484   14.3

It would be this:

> 469 13.3
>   470
>   471
>   472
>   473 
>   474 13.5
>   475
>   476
>   477
>   478
>   479 14.1
>   480
>   481
>   482
>   483
>   484 14.3

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the first part exactly, but in general, you can use Excel's [`AVERAGE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/average.php) function:

```
=AVERAGE(A1:A10)
=AVERAGE(A:A)
```

The first one will output the average of the values between `A1` and `A10` (inclusive), the second one will output the average of all values in the `A` column.

In the second part of your question, you ask to "expand" the time values with the measurement values. This is best done in a second sheet. Let's name the sheet with the data you have `Data`.

[image]

In the second sheet, write `469` in `A1`, `470` in `A2` and then you can drag it down to the final measurement time.

Then, in `B1` (of the second sheet we just started working on), add the following:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1, Data!$A$1:$B$200, 2, FALSE)), "", VLOOKUP(A1, Data!$A$1:$B$200, 2, FALSE))
```

Drag it down all the way to the last measurement time. You might have to change the two references to `$B$200` to something higher, like `$B$500` or whatever the highest row number is in the original `Data` spreadsheet.

This will add the measurement value for the corresponding time from the `Data` sheet, or it will just be an empty cell if there is no such value (e.g. no value for time `472`).

[image]

---

Some explanations to that formula (skip if not interested). The heart of the formula is the following:

```
VLOOKUP(A1, Data!$A$1:$B$200, 2, FALSE))
```

[`VLOOKUP`](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) searches for a value at another place and then returns that row. In this case, we want to find the value `A1` in `Data!$A$1:$B$200`, which is Excel's way of writing "the table `A1` to `B200` in the sheet `Data`". The `$` signs guarantee that the values will not be changed as we drag the formula down, since Excel will automatically update regular cell references such as `A1` in the formula.

So this will search for `A1` in that area of `Data` and it will return a row. `2` specifies what cell's value we want to use, which is the measurement time right next to the value we just searched for (e.g. we found `564` in `Data` but we want to get the corresponding value next to it, i.e. `12.9`).

`VLOOKUP` is a little dangerous in that it uses approximate values by default, which the last `FALSE` parameter prevents. To quote from microsoft.com [[Source](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)]:

> If an exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less than lookup_value is returned.

And we really don't want that in this case. (It beats me why this is the default behavior, to be honest.)

`VLOOKUP` with no approximate search returns `#N/A` for values it can't find, and we don't want that all over our spreadsheet. This is why we test the function first:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(...)), "", VLOOKUP(...))
```

In other words, if `VLOOKUP` returns `#N/A`, let's just write nothing (`""`); otherwise, let's write what `VLOOKUP` returns to us.